# Gitlab displays different users

Tags: gitlab, settings, commit

There are strange problem with my gitlab/git. I have new and old account. For example, I have a merge request. In 'Commits' tab it display commit and my new account , but in overview tab it display "Old username added 1 commit 1 hour ago". Git username and email set to new account. So what is the problem? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: This isn't a Git issue at all. GitLab is simply recording which account you're using when you run commands on GitLab, and you're using the old account to run the commands. Make sure your authentication (which is done by ssh or https, not by Git itself) is using the new account's new-and-different ssh key (if ssh) or username-and-"token" (password: a token *is* a password, really) (if https).

Comment: @torek so for ssh i need to create ssh key and use it when cloning?

Comment: Yes, or more precisely, a key-pair, consisting of a public key (which you give to others) and a private key (which you keep to yourself). They use the public key to encrypt stuff to send to you; you (or your software) decrypts that using your private key, and this proves to them that you hold the private key that goes with the public key. The public key itself then acts as proof that you are you, and that's what GitLab uses to determine who you are.

Comment: If two users have the *same* public/private key-pair, GitLab will associate that public key with just *one* of the two users, and both users will be identified as that one user. So don't do that. :-)

Comment: @torek thanks, i think i got its and will try.